# How to keep white spaces when using String.Concat

Tags: c#, string

To prevent the user from inputting anything besides letter or numbers, I am using

```
string.Concat(textbox.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit ));
```

However, I would like to prevent the Concat method from removing white spaces, and the Concat method does not take multiple arguments. Suggestions? Perhaps Regex would be smarter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space character isn't a letter or a digit so you need to change your `Where` clause, for examples:

```
string.Concat(textbox.Text.Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == ' '));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `Concat` that is removing whitespaces. `Where` is removing whitespaces, because whitespaces are neither letters not digits.

You just need to modify the `Where`:

```
string.Concat(textbox.Text.Where(x => char.IsLetterOrDigit(x) || char.IsWhiteSpace(x) ));
```

Since you mentioned regex, here is a regex to do it:

```
[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\s]
```

`Regex.Replace` the above with an empty string and you will get the result:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}\\s]", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can use `regex`

```
Regex.Replace(textbox.Text, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: You have a typo.  "" <-- needs " "

Comment: If you want to remove `non-letters` then the above code is fine, but if you want to replace them with spaces then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

*To prevent the user from inputting anything besides letter or numbers, I am using...*

Actually you do not prevent the user from entering anything, instead you transform/filter the input the user made (and remove unwanted characters there). From a user's perspective, this is quite confusing and might lead to unwanted behavior, would be better to validate the input and show the user some notification/info that what he has entered was not valid.